# Pdf invoice and Mailer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, prawn

I try to learn Rails and I'm stuck.
I have User, Job, Invoice and Customer models. I'm creating an invoice and Pdf invoice with Prawn. The Pdf invoice is not saved(I don't want to save pdf's, just to see the pdf in browser) and now I want a button to send pdf invoice by email. I have in invoice show view 2 buttons one for view Pdf and another send pdf by email.

```
= link_to 'View PDF', invoice_path(@invoice, format: "pdf")
\|
= link_to "Send Email", invoice_mail_path(current_user, @invoice), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary"
```

I have:

invoice_mailer.rb

```
default from: "example@yahoo.com"

  def invoice_mail(invoice, user, job)
    @invoice = invoice
    @user = user
    @job = job
    attachments["#{(@invoice.invoice_number)}.pdf"] = InvoicePdf.new(@invoice, view_context).render

    mail(to: 'example@yahoo.com',
         subject: "A new invoice from xxx")
  end
```

invoices_controller.rb

```
def invoice_mail

# @invoice = Invoice.last
@invoice = Invoice.new(@invoice)
@user = current_user
@job = current_user.jobs

InvoiceMailer.invoice_mail(@invoice, @user, @job).deliver_now

flash[:notice] = "Invoice has been sent."
redirect_to invoices_path 
end
```

routes.rb

```
get :invoice_mail, to: 'invoices#invoice_mail', as: :invoice_mail
```

In invoices_controller in def invoice_mail if I have

```
@invoice = Invoice.last
```

is working and is sending the email with pdf attached but is grabbing the last invoice. If I have

```
@invoice = Invoice.new(@invoice)
```

is give me error.

**What do I need instead of @invoice = Invoice.last to grab the current invoice ? Or what I did wrong ?**

When i hit send email button I have on terminal :

```
Started GET "/invoice_mail.16-446cd684-c756-4ea3-a820-17756f44098d" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-22 11:07:30 -0400
Processing by InvoicesController#invoice_mail as 
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ /Users/ovi_tsb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Invoice without an ID):

app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:124:in `invoice_mail'
```

Comment: "is give me error." What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@invoice = Invoice.new(@invoice)
```

This, in your controller, makes no sense. You're assigning a `@invoice` a nil value to the value of `Invoice.new(@invoice)`, which is the equivalent of `Invoice.new(nil)`. That shouldn't throw any errors, but it really doesn't make sense to do.

Presumably, what you want to do is find an invoice based on **ID**. Just like:

```
@invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
```

That means your request should include an `:id` parameter. If it does not, you need to include it. But I believe this should have it:

```
= link_to "Send Email", invoice_mail_path(current_user, @invoice), 
                        class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary"
```

Secondly, the `link_to` above need not include a `current_user`. `current_user` is a reference to the `User` grabbed by Rails via the user's session. In other words, it'll exist in your controller by default. So don't bother passing it:

```
= link_to "Send Email", invoice_mail_path(@invoice), 
                         class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary"
```

Lets clean up your controller with this new information:

```
def invoice_mail
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id]) # :id should be the invoice ID
  @jobs = current_user.jobs

  InvoiceMailer.invoice_mail(@invoice, current_user, @jobs).deliver_now
  flash[:notice] = "Invoice has been sent."
  redirect_to invoices_path 
end
```

Comment: Hi, Veridian. When I use @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id]) It give me : ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoicesController#invoice_mail  / Couldn't find Invoice without an ID

Comment: Are you passing the correct params[:id]? Edit your post with the logs appended after you hit that "Send Email" link.

Comment: Okay, so, your `invoice_mail_path` in your `routes.rb` file is likely not configured to accept any params. Whatever is looks like, try making it look like `/invoice_mail/:id` and retry the route. When routing GET requests need params specified. Now, when you click "Send Mail", it should pass the `:id` param along with it!

Comment: Superrrrr !!!!  It working an it passing good invoice number and everything. Now my routes is :  get '/invoice_mail/:id', to: 'invoices#invoice_mail', as: :invoice_mail. Now I have 550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed but is because I'm on local . Let my try on heroku and I'll accept you answer. Thank you.